# Sound is muted on startup with iBook G4 PPC

Tags: sound, indicator-sound

I have Ubuntu 12.04 running on a iBook G4 PPC. Every time I restart my sound is muted, how do I make it so the sound is automatically on.

Sound does work, after bootup I can manually un-mute it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a recent experience with this kind of Problem. I Follow these steps, and It solved for me. *(I don't know actually why it get solved)*

1. I opened `gstreamer-properties` by typing it in Dash
2. Select *Pulse Audio Sound Server* as the plugin for Default Audio output.
3. Then rebooting the machine after also removing the `.pulse` and `.pulse-cookie` from home folder

---

After Login, move the `.pulse` folder and `.pulse-cookie` file to another location and try rebooting.

For example, You can execute this command to move them in your Documents folder.

```
mv ./.{pulse,pulse-cookie} ./Documents/ -v
```

After opening a terminal.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I was successful in moving the files but it didn't seem to help at all. I restarted once and nothing, then raised the volume, restarted again, and still nothing.

Comment: @Adri1818 I've edited my answer. You may want to check the way I have recently used to fix my problem :-)